# Inherited Controls don't inherit Material Design Style

Tags: material-design-in-xaml

when using MaterialDesignForXamlToolkit one can bring in out of the box styled controls like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollBarMinimal}"
               TargetType="ScrollBar" />
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

The Listview itself and the scrollbar are displayed using Material Design.

But when I use a inherited control defined like this the Material Design style is not applied.

.cs

```
public class NavigationMenuListView : ListView, ICommandSource
{
    // add needed stuff
}
```

.xaml

```
<controls:NavigationMenuListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollBarMinimal}"
               TargetType="ScrollBar" />
    </ListView.Resources>
</controls:NavigationMenuListView>
```

Is there a proper way to use inherited controls? Or is this not supported?

Comment: Are you calling `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata()` on the static constructor of `NavigationMenuListView`?

Comment: Hi @LoRdPMN, no I don't. Shall I? As far as I understand that shouldn't be called in my case. At the moment, with the code above, the control is partly (and automatically) styled (like the font which is set correct). When I call  DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(...) it completely disappears. I will try to snoop it later to see what is really happening.